# PHP How to expire the session when you log-out to your page and how to retain the session when press back button

Tags: php, android, session

Can someone help me with my session expires? I just wanted to expire the session when I log-out to my page and how I can retain the session when I accidentally press the back button without any intention or I accidentally close my tab..

Can you give me some codes that might help to solve my problem? Thanks.

Here's the case.. I have a registration page, index page, main page, list of result from database page..

On my index.page, I have here a code:

```
//Start session
session_start();    
//Unset the variables stored in session
unset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']);
```

On my main page, I have here a:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']) || empty($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID'])) {
    header("Location: ".dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/index.php");

    die;
}
```

On my list of result page, I also have a

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']) || empty($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID'])) {
    header("Location: ".dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/index.php");

    die;
}
```

The problem is, when I register to my registration page and I am trying to access the new account that I created, whenever I submit it to be at the main page. I can't come to the page, it always returns the index.php..

What's good here is, when I accidentally press the back button and accidentally close the tab, I can still access my account.. But when I log-out it.. the session will expire.. This is somewhat I expected.. but it causes problem to my registration page. I cannot access the new created account.. Help.

Comment: Used `unset($_SEESION)` to expire ur session.

Comment: Pankaj I edited my question above. pls help me

Comment: No need to write `seesion_start()` on list of result page bcoz u have already added it on index page.

Comment: how about my index and main page?

Comment: Can u paste ur index file & main file code?

Comment: index page is Log-in and main page is next after the log-in.. after I created an account,  there is a button in a registration where going to be direct in main page but due on my code for session. it will direct it first to log-in then main page

Comment: Ok. Can u plz tell me that after successful registration you want user to be redirected to the main page or log in page. So that I can help u out.

Comment: after successful registration, it will now be direct to main page.. but what happening is after the successful registration, when I click the button that will direct to main page, It re-direct to login page.. and cannot anymore access the new created account.. after I sign the username and password, it always went to login page

Comment: on my log-in page.. I only have session_start(); unset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']);

Comment: on my main page i have session_start();
 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']) || empty($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID'])) {
     header("Location: ".dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/index.php");
    
     die;
   }

Comment: on my list of result page i have session_start();
 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']) || empty($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID'])) {
     header("Location: ".dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/index.php");
     
     die;
    }

Comment: Plz remove `unset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']);` on index page. Try it. Becoz what happening is that ur r unsetting the SESS_EMP_ID on index page. And same value ur checking on main page. But on main page it doesn't have any value.

Comment: the correct series would be, '''registration page''', '''main page''' then optional if they still wanted to view the '''list of result page'''. But, what is happening is '''registration page''', '''log in page''' cannot anymore access the main page by the new created account

Comment: Yes I get ur series. In php which ever action u called each n every time it will go to first index page & then the other page.

Comment: i tried to remove the unset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']); on index.php which is supposed to be my log-in page.. I tried to create a new account and try to direct to main page, but still it redirect to index page(login).. and still cannot access my account..

Comment: this is my code session_start();
 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']) || empty($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID'])) {
     header("Location: ".dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/index.php");
     
     die;
    } is this correct for expiring session?

Answer (score 0):

Press back button means:

Check session expries or not

For Example:

```
<?php
session_start()
if($_SESSION['sesion_varaiable']{
   //page to be displayed
}else{
  //redirect to login page
}
```

In logout.php file

Unset the sessions

```
  <?php
    session_destroy();
    ?>
```

or

```
 <?php
unset($_SESSION);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For log out u can try this:

```
//sample if condition
if($_REQUEST['mode'] == 'logout'){
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:'.path_to_login_page); //redirect to ur login page
}
```

Comment: I have on my log out session_start();
 session_destroy();
 echo("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
 window.location.href='index.php';
 </SCRIPT>
 ");

Comment: Plz used `session_unset();`   `session_destroy();` `header('Location:index.php');` for log out. Put ur log out action in some condition. As I have mention above.

Comment: ok Pankaj.. but still I cant access the new created account once I log it on my index page (Login)

Comment: For now you can comment ur `unset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']);` line on index page. Then run your application. Plz try this & let me know also.

Comment: i tried to remove the unset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']); on index.php which is supposed to be my log-in page.. I tried to create a new account and try to direct to main page, but still it redirect to index page(login).. and still cannot access my account..  Pankaj

Comment: this is my code session_start(); if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']) || empty($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID'])) { header("Location: ".dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/index.php"); die; } is this correct for expiring session?

Comment: No. This is for, if your `$_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']` variable is empty or not set then ur redirecting it to index page. For session expire, u have to used above code that have mentioned in ans. i.e `session_unset();` `session_destroy();` `header('Location:index.php');`

Comment: so why whenever I created an account then log-in it, I cant access but when I comment the session, I can access the account

Comment: Did u remove `unset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']);` on index page.

Comment: yes, I removed it.. nothing happens.. Still, i cant access the new created account.. do you have gmail account?

Comment: Do u noted it some where. So that can remove it from above.

Comment: I comment the unset($_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID']);, it was always redirecting to the index page (login). and cannot access my account

Comment: I need to see ur code so that I can help you clearly.

Comment: Please log-in to your gmail account.. you are not replying with my message